# How does the prefix 'hyper-' explain 'hyperopia' (farsightedness)?

Tags: etymology, greek

> [ [Etymonline :](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hyperopia) ] 
>       "very acute vision," 1861, Modern Latin, from [*hyper-*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=hyper-&allowed_in_frame=0) "over, exceedingly, to excess" + Greek *ops* "eye" (see [eye](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=eye&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)), Latin with abstract noun ending. [...]

To what does the prefix 'hyper-' refer exactly? My 2 conjectures for the referent of 'hyper-': 1.  'far' in 'farsightedness'. 2. the excessively backward focal point. Though not an ocular expert, I do understand, and so ask not about, the basic medical explanation. Please tell me if I included too many pictures of hyperopia from Google:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it matter?  Either "far" in "far-sighted" or "excess", in "the focal point is excessively far back".  (Understand that whoever first picked the term just grabbed the Latin roots that sounded good and jammed them together.)

Comment: LePress, you know I'm one of your biggest fans here on SE, so can you do me a favor and elaborate on your reasons for needing a *rationale* for words? Have you ever googled the *principle of the arbitrary sign* (which goes by many names, that's simply the one I personally find most descriptive)? If you could do a detailed Meta-post on your personal motivations in this regard, my take is it would go a long way towards generating interest in and sympathy (and useful answers) for this type of question.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you for your continued support. Yes; I can elaborate a little here. In this case, I am mainly interested in the possible medical definitions or connotations behind this word formation; I would suspect that some physician invented it, for some medical reason? Or it could have been random, in which case I still wish to know. I will return to your last sentence later.

Comment: @LePressentiment Yes, that makes sense, but I'm not so concerned with this specific question (cool image btw), but more curious (really curious!) about the broader pattern of why, internally, you feel a deep thirst for words, in general, to "make sense" (with respect to their origins, evolution, and semantic drifts, of course, not their literal definitions). Why care at all? If I defined and popularized the word "frobnicate" to mean "tweak", and all the world adopted it, would you care why I picked that specific sequence of letters? If so, why so?

Comment: It's possible the grail could be found: the coiner of the term could've said whether they had in mind one or the other or both (excessive clarity of vision at long distances or a focal point in excess of, that is, beyond the retina). I could not find that grail. At the time of the earliest use I could uncover, 1876, the term was obviously already established. Thus, historically, I can't ascertain which excess was referenced by 'hyper-', or whether both excesses were intended. Without that grail, I'm afraid your answers will be little better than surmise and opinion.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, but the images are not mine. I care as ONLY sometimes (NOT always, per the Etymological Fallacy), etymology can illuminate a word's semantic field (as indicated by some questions on this site). Also, randomness (as your example "frobnicate"  evidences) is a separate reason from uncertainty (in etymology). Does this make sense?

Comment: @LePressentiment Yes, but I'm asking a slightly different question. I'm not asking why it sometimes turns out that a word's current meaning hasn't diverged enough from its ultimate origins to make the latter irrelevant to the former. I'm asking, out of my own curiosity, why it appears, to an independent observer, that you *desire* for (all) words to make sense, i.e. that their meanings be related to their forms. It seems to bother you if a word's current meaning is at odds with or can't be reconciled with the letters, morphemes, or lexemes used to compose it. Why is that?

Comment: @DanBron Sorry if I misunderstood. Also, please feel free to question me out of your curiosity; I welcome your advice as always. 1. I never expect or intend `for (all) words to make sense, i.e. that their meanings be related to their forms`, because I accept that some words' etymology is ambiguous, unknown or inexistent (eg: if words were created randomly as your example above).

Comment: @DanBron 2. You are correct that I *AM* bothered `if a word's current meaning is at odds with or can't be reconciled with the letters, morphemes, or lexemes used to compose it.` One main reason: while I can and must tolerate that change in language is inevitable and natural, I fear changes too extreme because they preclude understanding and totally confuse over time (eg: Shakespearean vs 2016 English): see http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/4033/5306. I also note that Francophones appear to fear language change more than Anglophones.  Do my reasons make sense?

Comment: @LePressentiment That sheds a little light, thanks. Of course reading something written 400 years ago will be difficult, and 1000 years ago starts bordering on a different language. But, as you say, that's just inevitable, a fact, so nothing to fear at all. We have ways to recover meaning. But none of that seems to have bearing on your dislike for *modern* writings and words to somehow connect to their roots? Word X means Y and has etymology Z, surely there's nothing confusing about X, even if Z is long and tortured, because X means Y *even when you don't know Z*, right? With no confusion.

Comment: @LePressetiment Etymonline is wrong. The other posters told you already, hyperopia literally means "beyond the eye (i.e. retina)."

Comment: @LePressentiment On the other hand, I would like to make a very important side note. It seems you do not understand how etymological research is done, cf. "I accept that some words' etymology is ambiguous, unknown or inexistent." **There is no such thing as "inexistent etymology"** [sic!]. We may not know it yet, for different reasons, but it is always the end result of our extremely time-consuming, meticulous comparative research. Linguists propose etymological analysis based on linguistic, anthropological etc. evidence; in other words, **linguists try to reconstruct its development**.

Comment: @DanBron `X means Y even when you don't know Z`: For most, but not all words, yes. For example, knowing Z does aid one in understanding the origin of the contradictory meaning behind auto-antonyms (eg: sanction)? Also, one need not know Z, but knowing Z does not hurt, correct? You need not know Z

Comment: @AlexB. You are correct, thanks. I should NOT have written **inexistent**; I meant **inexistent** in the resources at this present time, not for eternity.

Comment: @LePressentiment I start to sense we will go in circles.  I was not interested in how you could apply the etymology, but why you are bothered that when a word's current meaning are at odds with its morphology. Why does it matter at all? Words are opaque symbols, you learn how it's spelled and what it means, and you accept it may have more than one meaning (even more than one *contradictory* meaning, as you point out with contranyms), and you move on. Why do you need more "aid" in understanding it? Why investigate Z at all as it pertains to meaning?

Comment: @DanBron Should we initiate a Chat Room? As I am inexperienced, do you encountered any opinions from the professional Historical Linguisticians on etymology as I have used it? I prefer to read their arguments and counterarguments before I answer, lest I do go in circles.

Comment: @LePressentiment I don't know how to start a chat, but I'm happy to participate in one. I am about to leave the office for the day, though, so I won't have time for proper back-and-forth until tomorrow. In re: historical linguistics, the bottom line which they have produced you are already very familiar with: the etymological fallacy. Linguists study etymology because it's a field in its own right, like archaeology. Even etymologists themselves just accept words as meaning what they mean for the purposes of everyday reading, writing, and speaking.

Comment: IOW: even for professional etymologists, while knowing the history behind the words used in a given utterance may make it more *interesting*, it does not make it more *clear*. Clarity comes from knowing *what* words mean, *not* how they came to mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Hyperopia*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hyperopia) (farsightedness or longsightedness) is a condition in which the eyeball's shape causes the light rays to hit the retina before they converge.  That is, the the lens places the focal point of the light beyond the retina (hence the *hyper*, Greek for *over*, *in excess*). The diagrams in your question show this imaginary focal point in that position.

Comment: Not the downvoter, btw, but perhaps it was because I could just as easily say, "Hyperopia is a condition in which the eye can resolve objects at distances over or exceeding the distance at which a normal eye can. (hence the *hyper*, Greek for *over, in excess*)"

Comment: @Jim Historically speaking, questions which seek rational explanations of arbitrary situations, in direct conflict with the philosophy advanced by the etymological fallacy, have been downvoted. And, similarly, historically speaking, answers to ill-founded questions (i.e. those based on false premises, express or implied) have also been downvoted, as an expression of frustration with such worldviews (and to discourage similar answers, and by that mechanism, such questions). In this particular case, the situation is exacerbated by this particular OP's insistence that words should make sense.